# How to subscribe to a static event of a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, events

I have a generic class that has a static event:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    static public event EventHandler MyEvent;
}
```

Is it possible to subscribe to this event *without* specifying a type `T`? I tried like this, but the compiler won't compile it.

```
public class MyClass2
{
    public MyClass2()
    {
        MyClass</*this can't be empty, but I don't want to specifiy*/>.MyEvent += this.EventHandler;
    }   
}
```

Comment: If you're not interested in the type then why not refactor the code so that the event is in a non-generic class.

Comment: I want the event be fired for all instances of my class no matter of what type it is.

Answer (score 1):

The static field(s) in a generic type `<T>` are **per `T`**; it doesn't make sense to not care about the `T`, because `MyClass<Foo>.MyEvent` is **completely different** to `MyClass<Bar>.MyEvent` - it can have different subscribers, and invoking one doesn't invoke the other. If you want them to be shared, then you'll need to define the event in a non-generic class, i.e.

```cs
static class MyClass {
    static public event EventHandler MyEvent;
}
class MyClass<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Note that static events are often, but not always, a bad design choice.

Comment: Specifically, make sure you unsubscribe from static events otherwise you might get a memory leak.

Comment: I think I found a solution for my problem. When I use `object` as T, the event gets fired for all instances of my class:  `MyClass<object>.MyEvent += this.EventHandler;`

Comment: @user2190035 that's ... horrifying